# Is there a less verbose and kludgy way to make otherwise-null SQL parameters safe?

Tags: c#, sql-server, varchar

I've got code for inserting a record into a SQL Server table which in some cases has some null values (if not replaced with pseudo-null (empty) vals first). Specifically, they are varchars.

If I don't check for null and assign string.empty in those instances:

```
if (null == _PatternOrdinal)
{
    rs.PatternOrdinal = string.Empty;
}
else
{
    rs.PatternOrdinal = _PatternOrdinal;
}
```

...it throws the exception, "*The parameterized query '(@Unit varchar(25),@ReportID int,@NextExecution datetime,@NextEx' expects the parameter '@PatternOrdinal', which was not supplied.*"

IOW, if the code is simply this:

```
rs.PatternOrdinal = _PatternOrdinal;
```

...instead of the if block above, it crashes.

So I have to do that with several parameters. Is there a less verbose way to circumvent this periodic derailing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
rs.PatternOrdinal = _PatternOrdinal ?? string.Empty;
```

It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

But be aware that an empty string and a `null` value are not the same. An empty string is still a value, but a `null` means that there is no defined value.

In those cases where you need to save `null` values you should use `DbNull.Value` instead of an empty string.